# How to serialize very large object in Hadoop Writable

Tags: java, hadoop, serialization, mapreduce, writable

Hadoop Writable interface relies on `"public void write(DataOutput out)"` method. It looks like behind DataOutput interface, Hadoop uses DataOutputStream, which uses a simple array under the cover.

When I try to write a lot of data in DataOutput in my reducer, I get:

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM
>   limit
>           at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3230)
>           at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:113)
>           at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
>           at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:140)
>           at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
>           at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)

Looks like the system is unable to allocate the continuous array of the requested size.
Apparently, increasing the heap size available to the reducer does not help - it is already at 84GB (-Xmx84G)

If I cannot reduce the size of the object that I need to serialize (as the reducer constructs this object by combining the object data), what should I try to work around this problem?

Comment: Can you give more details about your key/value type, serialization and the output format ?

Comment: That's the file (I am trying to get this OOS to work for my data) https://github.com/thinkaurelius/faunus/blob/master/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/faunus/FaunusVertex.java

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **-Xms** e.g. **-Xms40G** rather than -Xmx84G

Comment: Consider also writing about why such keys should be used